# Brachistochrone curve counterpart

Tags: calculus-of-variations, curves

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve)'s description of a brachistochrone curve is

> the one lying on plane between a point A and a lower point B, where B is not directly below A, on which a bead slides frictionlessly under the influence of a uniform gravitational field to a given end point in the shortest time.

I was wondering if there was a counterpart to the brachistochrone curve, which would be the curve such that, given the aformentionned conditions, a bead would travel from A to B in the longest, finite amount of time. 
I assume such curve would be some kind of concave version of the brachistochrone.